# How to get current category id while placing product order in Magento's admin section

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to get current category id while placing order. 
I have tried code as below,

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');  
$Category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();  
$currentCatId= $Category ->getId();
```

It is giving empty value.

Comment: This code works fine -   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
$ids    = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryId = (isset($ids[0]) ? $ids[0] : null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); 
 $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
if(count($categoryIds) ){
  // YOUR CODE
}
```